# Undefined is not an Object (evaluatig'_native.NavigationHelperContext.Provider')

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I was trying to make a material top tab navigator using library `@react-navigation/material-top-tabs` but encountered an error. I did exactly shown in docs still cant find the error
here is code of my navigator screen.

```
const tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator()


export class Home extends Component {


      render() {
        return (
          <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
          <View>
            <Appbar.Header>
            <Appbar.Action icon="home" />
            <Appbar.Content title="Home" />
            </Appbar.Header>
              <tab.Navigator initialRouteName={CurrentLoc} tabBarOptions={{
                activeTintColor: '#04395e',
                swipeEnabled: true
              }}>
                <tab.Screen name="Curent Location" component={CurrentLoc}  options={{
              tabBarLabel: 'Current Location'}}/>
                <tab.Screen name="India" component={IndiaStat}  options={{
              tabBarLabel: 'India'}}/>
              </tab.Navigator>
          </View>
          </NavigationContainer>
        )
      }
    }

export default Home
```

Screenshot of error:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y533a.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you are using the latest version of @react-navigation/native

[see issue here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8166)